# How do I access Docker service in the host (Windows Server 2022) from a Hyper-V VM (Windows Server 2022)?

Tags: docker, ssl

I spent 2 full days googling and trying and still cannot resolve the issue.
I am running a Docker container that provides an api for the host machine (Windows Server 2022) to call.

```
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Environment: production
2023-08-01 18:09:56    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2023-08-01 18:09:56    Use a production WSGI server instead.
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Debug mode: off
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Environment: production
2023-08-01 18:09:56    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2023-08-01 18:09:56    Use a production WSGI server instead.
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Debug mode: on
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2023-08-01 18:09:56  * Restarting with stat
2023-08-01 18:09:57  * Running on https://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2023-08-01 18:09:57  * Debugger is active!
```

Using postman, I am able to access the service with http status 200 OK.
But when I am try to access the service using https://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000, I get error for cert validation, which is normal as the cert is self signed.

```
ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN2022-XXXX
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (InternalLAN):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-XX-5D-XX-56-15
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c12f:faa2:7ccd:2d47%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.200(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.0
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 587208029
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-XX-01-2C-37-96-4A-A0-36-BC-74-30-21
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-XX-7D-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cae2:3b98:3cf3:5591%41(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.224.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 687871325
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-XX-00-01-2C-37-96-4A-A0-36-BC-74-30-21
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Minikube):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-91-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::16aa:ab17:bf03:fc05%47(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.77(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.0
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 788534621
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-XX-2C-37-96-4A-A0-36-BC-74-30-21
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet Right Side:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-36-XX-74-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::26ba:f612:b0eb:fe36%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, 26 July 2023 11:58:49 am
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 1 August 2023 11:44:44 pm
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 245380796
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-XX-2C-37-XX-4A-A0-36-BC-74-30-21
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.XX.XX.162
                                       194.XX.XX.161
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internet):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-36-BC-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2e42:925e:84e6:dc21%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 396375740
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2C-37-XX-4A-XX-36-BC-74-30-21
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.XX.XX.162
                                       194.XX.XX.161
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I have added the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authority and also added them in the Postman's setting.

From the Docker logs, it seems like the call cannot even reach the service.
I can't ping the Ip address with https but ok with http.

This is my configuration:

1. Host running on Windows Server 2022
2. Hyper-V VMs running Windows Server 2022
3. Windows Dockers with containers running

IMPORTANT: I am trying to access the Docker service from another hyper-V VM running Windows Server 2022. So, technically, the question is

***How do I access Docker service in the host (Windows Server 2022) from a Hyper-V VM (Windows Server 2022)?***

I am at lost on what is going on now and super confused.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: _I get error, which is a bunch of garbage._ Is not very explicative, please update the question with the complete error log.

Comment: I think I understand why. It is because the cert is self-signed and therefore can never pass cert validation